# calcular en array entero positivo más pequeño –mayor que 0–

Tags: php, script, lógica

Estoy tratando de hacer una pequeña función que me calcule el entero positivo más pequeño mayor que 0 que NO aparezca en unos arrays, pero no consigo saber como puedo calcular esto...

Estoy tratando de hacer esto

```
function checkArray()
    {
        $A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2];
        //$A = [1, 2, 3];
        //$A = [-1, -3];


        for($i=0; $i<count($A); $i++){
            if($A[$i] > 0){
                return max($A) - 1;
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

y eso me devuelve 5, pero me temo que estoy haciendo trampa, ya que estoy restando 1 al mayor...Pero es el resultado correcto.

Para los otros dos arrays es a la inversa en este array `$A = [1, 2, 3];` me debe mostrar 4 y en este otro `$A = [-1, -3]` me debe de mostrar 1

En estos arrays, que solo son de ejemplo se pueden dar estos casos:

```
N(el contenido del array) es un entero en el rango [1..100,000];
Cada elemento del array $A es un entero del rango [−1,000,000..1,000,000].
```

LLevo bastante rato intentnado averiguar como puedo calcular estos casos, pero me encuentro bastante perdido.

Agradezco toda ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución podría ser

```
<?php
function checkArray($A)
    {
     $i=1;
     while (true)
        {
            if (!in_array($i, $A))
               break;   
            $i++;   
        }       
     return $i;   
    }

echo "Mínimo entero positivo no presente en el array es ".checkArray([1,2,3,5,3,6]);
```

A ver si te sirve. Es lo más simple que se me ha ocurrido.
**EDITO**
Aunque este código funciona, esta modificación lo mejora, digamos que es más elegante y  lógico.

```
function checkArray($A)
    {
     $i=1;
     while (in_array($i, $A))
        {
        $i++;   
        }       
     return $i;   
    }

echo "Mínimo entero positivo no presente en el array es ".checkArray([1,2,3,5,3,6]);
```

Comment: Podrías poner directamente `!in_array($i, $A)` como condición del `while`

Comment: Es verdad!!! Fallo de principiante Agggggggggggggggg! Con  while (in_array($i, $A)) mejora la solución.

Comment: No, es que el while debe repetirse mientras el entero **exista en la lista**. Me explico: lista [1, 3,5,2] empiezas  con el 1, **está** (in_array(1, lista) es **true**), sigue ahora con el 2, está pues sigue ahora con el 3, está pues sigue ahora con el 4, **no está** (in_array(4, lista) es **false**) se para.  
El while se repite mientras la **condición sea cierta**.

Comment: Tenes razón! :)